# Davisson-Germer experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, reflection, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

[Davisson and Germer's experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davisson%E2%80%93Germer_experiment) confirmed the wave-particle duality of matter.

In this experiment a slowed down electron beam is reflected by the surface of a nickel crystal, which is able to split the electron beam into several parts, each of which is characterized by a reflection angle, rising a diffraction pattern quite similar to that of the X-rays.

Is what I'm about to write right? This phenomenon is possible because the surface of the nickel crystal is not regular, but is formed by microscopic grooves capable of rising to the phenomenon of diffraction.

Comment: you are misunderstanding the difference between "regular" and "smooth".

Answer (score 1):

You *must not* think of the crystal structure of the metal as a classical object. All the top minds of the time birthing quantum theory, were furiously treating the problem of ``billiard ball" electrons bouncing around in the "pegs" of the ionic crystal lattice. All of that work are wasted, because there is no way to get even qualitatively the correct picture out of this.

Instead, the electron propagation at the junction of this air/vacuum to crystal surface, has to be treated as a wave. Only then can you get anywhere near the correct result. We already hinted to you: The use of the word ``diffraction" connotates wave behaviour.